# R-Packages: mdgsa installation errors

Tags: r, r-package, bioconductor

1: package ‘mdgsa’ is not available for Bioconductor version '3.18'

I use the latest R version 4.3.2.

The above mentioned packages should be supported for my R version and Bioconductor version.

Any idea why this still doesn't work?

I also tried

```
BiocManager::install("mdgsa", type="binary")
```

But does not seem to work on Linux.